# Specifying height of divs as 100% of container minus height of sibling div

Tags: html, css

I've got a divs in the following layout

```
<html style="height:100%">
<body style="height:100%">
    <div id="divBody" style="height:100%;width:1000px">
        <div id="divHeader" style="height:30px"></div>
        <div id="divContent" style="height:100%">
            <div id="divLeft" style="height:100%; float:left; width:200px; border-left:1px solid black"></div>
            <div id="divRight" style="width:800px"></div>
        </div>
    <div>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is that divContent how has a height of 100% of the body.  What I need it to do is take up the entire height of divBody minus the height of divHeader. So I set the height of divContent to auto:

```
<html style="height:100%">
<body style="height:100%">
    <div id="divBody" style="height:100%;width:1000px">
        <div id="divHeader" style="height:30px"></div>
        <div id="divContent" style="height:auto">
            <div id="divLeft" style="height:100%; float:left; width:200px; border-left:1px solid black"></div>
            <div id="divRight" style="width:800px"></div>
        </div>
    <div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now divContent's height is correct, it is 100% of divBody minus the height of divHeader, but now the height of divLeft does not fill 100% of it's parent (divContent).  How can I get the best of both worlds here?

Comment: I would use jQuery's css method for this.

Comment: What is the purpose of having it set to 100% height? Is is just to display a different background? To enable scrolling? Rounded corners?

Comment: Because from a web application perspective, the whole look and feel of the application makes more sense if it encompasses the entire window, just just part that has content.

Answer (score 6):

Since you know the height of `#divHeader` is 30px, the simple answer to your question would be to use `calc()` on `#divContent` like this:

```
#divContent {
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
}
```

The tough part is to set height of a sibling like `#divContent` when the height of the other sibling(s) are unknown or dynamic. That's when [CSS Flex](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) comes in handy:

```
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.top {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.bottom {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Element with class `bottom` will use 100% height minus the height of its siblings. The `flex-shrink: 0` rule is important, primarily for iOS devices, to avoid shrinking on the sibling.

[Working example on Codepen here](https://codepen.io/calsal/pen/bGdgyBX).

Answer (score 1):

You should go on with the percentages instead of using fix amount of pixels for the header.
The widht of header and content should be 100%, but the height "auto", so it actually adjusts to their real need within the body div you're using.

Regarding to div left and right, both should set to height 100% I guess

Comment: confirmed, left and right with height to 100% is ok... but again, as sebastien put it, use percentages.

Comment: I've set the header and content height to auto, no change, it still doesn't cause the divLeft and divRight to fill the entire height.

Answer (score 0):

If all you care about is the height of the two columns and the fixed header height, there's a CSS hack that can help you achieve that.

Consider this HTML:

```
<html style="height:100%">
<body style="height:100%">
    <div id="divBody">
        <div id="divHeader">Header</div>
        <div id="divContent">
            <div id="divLeft">Left</div>
            <div id="divRight">Right</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>​
```

And the following CSS:

```
#divBody {
    height: 100%;
    width: 1000px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#divHeader {
    height:30px;
    background-color: Yellow;
}

#divContent {
    height:auto;
    background-color: Aqua;
    position: relative;
}

#divLeft {        
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    border-left:1px solid black;
    background-color: Azure;

    padding-bottom: 30000px;
    margin-bottom: -30000px;
}

#divRight {
    height: 100%;
    width:800px;
    background-color: Pink;

    padding-bottom: 30000px;
    margin-bottom: -30000px;
}
```

Here's JSFiddle with the illustration: http://jsfiddle.net/3rDNC/

```
​
```

Comment: Wow, this does appear to work, but I don't understand what the padding and margins are actually doing.  How is this for cross browser support?

Answer (score 0):

this is an old question but here is my two cents using calc(100% - 30px) to subtract the header size:

```
#divContent {
    height: calc(100% - 30px);
    background-color: Aqua;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: How would you do this if the 30px is relative and you don't have any fixed height?