# Set the height of div based on the height of its sibling

Tags: css

I have HTML elements like this.

```
<div id="A">
    <div id="B"></div>
    <div id="C"></div>
</div>
```

Both "B" and "C" have child elements. For "B", its height is dynamic, based on its content.
Now, I want to set the height of "C" to height of "A" minus the height of "B". Does anybody know how to do this through CSS?

Comment: `#A` will extend when you add data to `#B`, therefore height of `#C` will always be `height(#A) - height(#B)`

Comment: Yea, what's the height of A?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specifying height of divs as 100% of container minus height of sibling div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609531/specifying-height-of-divs-as-100-of-container-minus-height-of-sibling-div)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `css tables`.

**It works like this:**

The first table row takes up as much space as it needs.

Then give the second row a height of 100% and it fills up the remaining height of the table.

### Markup

```
<div class="a">
     <div class="b" >
         something
     </div>
     <div class="c" >
         something else
    </div>
</div>
```

### (Relevant) CSS

```
.a
{
    display:table;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
.b
{
    width: 100px;
    display:table-row;

}
.c
{
    display:table-row;
    height:100%;
    width: 100px;
}
```

**[FIDDLE1](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/ZDY4P/1/)**  **[FIDDLE2](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/ZDY4P/2/)**

Comment: Thanks Danield, it works. But if set a margin to "A", it seems the height calculation doesn't consider "margin" value. for example, if "margin-top" of A is 10px, height of "B" is 20px, the height of "C" is set to 80px, but I want to make its value 100px-10px-20px=70px.

Comment: @wyfeizj margin-top moves the whole table down. I think you mean padding-top. In any case, check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZDY4P/3/ - I have added the box-sizing property. Use inspect element to verify that  c=70

Comment: Thanks Danield, the issue is fixed.